fread() takes 60GB of RAM to load a 22GB CSV dataset
I am loading a CSV file into RStudio using fread() and despite the file being 22GB large, I can see my memory usage at 60 of my 64GB. Why is that? This becomes a problem right after as I need to join this datatable with another, leading to an RStudio crash.
To be clear, uploading the CSV using fread is the first operation I perform in the script.

Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/q/76456801/680068

The duplicate answer isn't an answer.  This is simpler.  An integer may be stored in one byte in a csv file, yet is four bytes in memory, Ditto for eight bytes for a double aka R's "numeric".  Ascii filesize is a very poor proxy for memory size, this can simply be larger.  The object is not stored in any compressed form in memory.

Check out the fst package.
